# How to get summary of Cities from States

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

[image]

I have a `State` and a `Cities` table in my SQL Server database (as you can see in the screenshot below). In my C# WinForms project, I'm trying to generate states and number of cities in every state by using a LINQ query, but it doesn't work as I want.

Here is my code:

```
var states = (from u in db.States
              join c in db.City on u.StateId equals c.StateId
              group u by u.City into g 
              select new 
              {
                  StateId=  u.StateId, 
                  State Name = u.StateName,  // Maybe g.Key here ??
                  Total Cities = g.Count     // and here I am not sure
              }).ToList();

 dgvStates.DataSource = states;
```

Comment: `it doesnt work as I want` what do you want? What output are you expecting and what output you are actually getting?

Comment: you need to group by state not city.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  Iwant as you see the image.

Comment: Answer posted by Roman below helped you?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya , not realy I only see one row in my gridview with Totalcities as "Title" and value of 3. Those are states. It's is totaly wrong .. ;)

Comment: Can  you share the output which you are getting after using the answer below

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  I see one output in my gridView with one row and one column. Column title = "Total Cities" and row value = "3".

Comment: That's weird.... Do you have properties set of gridView at the design time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var states = from u in db.States
             join c in db.City on u.StateId equals c.StateId
             group u by u.StateName into g 
             select new 
             {
                StateName = g.Key,
                TotalCities = g.Count()
             };
```

See example https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bqhTM

Result of the code above

[image]

Comment: not realy helped, I only see one row in my gridview with Totalcities as "Title" and value of 3. Those are states. It's is totaly wrong .. ;)

Comment: Sory man, I hade dgvStates.Columns[0].Visible = false; in my code, thats why I couldn't get results. Now its workin oerfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code can be work :

```
public void LoadStates()
        {

            try
            {
                TESTEntities db = new TESTEntities();

                // cmbProvince.Text = "";

                var states = (from u in db.States


                                select new
                                {
                                    u.StateId,

                                    u.StateName,
                                    u.Cityies.Count
                                }).ToList();


                dgvStates.DataSource = states;
                dgvStates.Columns[0].Visible = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Comment: thank you my dear, it's working this one with Unusual characters.

Comment: I have send email for special count on province part :). I glad to help you. Thank for return.